# When packaging ipa file got Error:mx.logging.targets::LineFormattedTarget could not be found and compile-abc fails

Tags: apache-flex, air, ipa

I have updated air sdk for compiling my application. I had flex 4.6 with air3.9 for compilation and air 24 for packaging for both apk and ipa. Now I need air 24 for compilation also. I get: Error:mx.logging.targets::LineFormattedTarget could not be found while packaging ipa file. Can anyone help me? I checked it starts with air 22, I mean i compiled it with flex4.6_air_21 and it worked, but with 22 it starts giving that error

Comment: I am not using IDE here. It is done in console with ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied with ant tasks. We had different flextasks.jar in previous sdk. When we copied them over to new sdk it solved the problem. Overlaying FlexSDK and Air SDK had nothing to do with the problem, as first you are using flex sdk for compilation and then you are using air sdk for transpiration and packaging (for iOS and android). You can have both those sdk separately, as long as you point to proper tool inside them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to overlay the AIR sdk onto the Flex sdk.
Instructions are here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html

> Exit Flash Builder.
>
> (Optional) Back up the Flex SDK by copying the entire directory.
>
> In Flash Builder, for example, copy the directory at:
>
> Windows: C:/Program Files/Adobe/Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0
>
> Mac OS: /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0
>
> Download the appropriate AIR SDK file for your operating system from
>   www.adobe.com/products/air/sdk/, and save it to the root directory of
>   the Flex SDK.
>
> Windows: AIRSDK_Compiler.zip
>
> Mac OS: AIRSDK_Compiler.dmg
>
> Extract the contents of the AIR SDK archive and overwrite the existing
>   SDK files.
>
> Windows: Right-click the ZIP file and select Extract All, or use a
>   decompression tool of your choice.
>
> Mac OS: In Terminal, run these commands:
>
> hdiutil attach AIRSDK_Compiler.dmg cp -rf /Volumes/AIR\ SDK/*
>   /path-to-empty-FLEXSDK-directory If you have trouble overwriting files
>   due to file permissions, try these commands:
>
> sudo hdiutil attach AIRSDK_Compiler.dmg sudo cp -rf /Volumes/AIR\
>   SDK/* /path-to-empty-FLEXSDK-directory (Optional) To access the new
>   AIR 3.4 APIs, update your application descriptor file to the 3.4
>   namespace.
>
> To update the namespace, change the xmlns attribute in your
>   application descriptor to:
>
> (Optional) To ensure that the output SWF file targets SWF version 17,
>   pass an additional compiler argument: -swf-version=17.

Comment: First of all I am not using FB. I compile it by ant. It does not help with my problem.

Comment: mx.logging.targets::LineFormattedTarget is in the Flex package... did you overlay the AIR SDK on top of the Flex SDK?